# Java: protected or public access for library methods that I intend to override only?

Tags: java, methods, access-modifiers

I'm writing a framework library where I have some methods that I only intend to be overridden, never to be called outside the library. However there is no security risk in making them `public` either.
I kind of had the impression that methods that are meant to be overridden are declared `public` in libraries and `protected` is only used when there is some security risk?
If there's no feasible security risk by making them public is there any reason to choose one or the other ?

Comment: I think the general advice would be to use `protected`. In case someone wants it as public, (s)he can also make it public, or just use it from the same package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Security is never the matter at hand, since reflection can circumvent package access. 'protected' is a way to communicating to human beings that the class is not designed to operate in a sensible way if someone calls the method from outside the class or its subclasses.

Answer (score 1):

This is basically a question of style. My rule of thumb is to have the most restrictive policy possible - i.e., prefer `protected` to `public`. If, in the future, you decide you do want to expose these methods, you can always make them `public`. If you start with them being `public` and have to change their signature later, though, you'd be in risk of breaking someone else's code who may have used them by mistake.

Comment: "If you start with them being `pubic` and […]"  Please, make it `public`, not `pubic`.  ;)

Comment: @MartinThorsenRanang as far as typos go, this is definitely one of the more embarrassing ones. Thanks for pointing that out. Edited and fixed.